# base64 decode not working

Tags: c, openssl, base64

I have the following code:

```
char *encoded = "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Qgc3RyaW5n";
char *unbase = unbase64(encoded,strlen(encoded));
printf("original: %s\n",unbase);
free(unbase);


char *unbase64(unsigned char *input,int length)
{
    BIO *b64,*bmem;
    char *buff = (char *)malloc(length);
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(input,length);
    bmem = BIO_push(b64,bmem);
    BIO_read(bmem,buff,length);
    BIO_free_all(bmem);
    return buff;
}

char *base64(const unsigned char *input,int length)
{
    BIO *bmem,*b64 = NULL;
    BUF_MEM *bptr;
    b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bmem = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    b64 = BIO_push(b64,bmem);
    BIO_write(b64,input,length);
    BIO_flush(b64);
    BIO_get_mem_ptr(b64,&bptr);
    char *buff = (char *)malloc(bptr->length);
    memcpy(buff,bptr->data,bptr->length-1);
    buff[bptr->length-1] = 0;
    BIO_free_all(b64);
    return buff;
}
```

which doesn't show the decoded string.

base64 encoding is working just fine, so what am I doing wrong?

Edit: found the answer ... base64 decoding requires '\n'

Comment: I'm using openssl already cause it is needed in other functions in my program so there is no need to create functions which are already defined in openssl

Comment: @RahulTripathi he doesn't need base64 decoding by-algoroithm, and certainly not in a language unrelated to this question. he simply wants to know what may be wrong in the BIO setup he has that would make OpenSSL's base6 bio-filter fail.

Comment: Where was the `'\n'` needed? At the end of `encoded`?

Comment: yes, the encoded string must end in \n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSSL API is dreadful to use, so I commend you on your insanity. Regardless, as you've eluded to in-comment, the decoder requires a newline unless you specifically tell it otherwise, which the code below does:

```
char *unbase64(void *input, int length)
{
    char *res = malloc(length);
    BIO *bmem = BIO_new_mem_buf(input, length);
    BIO *b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    BIO_set_flags(b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);
    bmem = BIO_push(b64, bmem);

    long n = BIO_read(bmem, res, length);
    if (n > 0)
        res[n] = 0;
    else
        res[0] = 0; // note: this is an error state.

    BIO_free_all(bmem);

    return res;
}
```

Run against your data, the following is the result

```
original: this is a test string
```

Yeah, because *that's* intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient memory allocation

```
// char *buff = (char *)malloc(length);
char *buff = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
// may also need
buff[length] = '\0';
```

Suspect additional issues.

Comment: it is very strange that the same function is working good in another context